# Unable to do multithreading in C++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

So I started to learn c++ and I come across multithreading, but there is one problem: It gives me the error `main.cpp|12|error: 'thread' was not declared in this scope` although I have included the `<thread>` library in my code.
I use Code::Blocks and `GNU GCC Complier` on Windows.
Here is an example of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void test(){
    cout<<"hello, I am a thread !";
}

int main(){

thread t1(test);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not the solution to the problem you describe, but you need to `t1.join()` before it's destroyed.

Comment: Why are you using "Code::Blocks and GNU GCC Complier on Windows." when MSVC is available free of charge for educational purposes? Microsoft IDE way surpasses CodeBlocks